# Messing up the time numbers and trying to sort them

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file like this and I want the date field numbers to be converted to history like (2021.7.22) and replaced again using Python in the history field.

[image]

A friend sent me a code that almost answered me, but there is still a bug in the code.

This is the code I used

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.read_excel('apal.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
output = {}
for ws, df in dfs.items():
    if 'date' in df.columns:
        df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: f'{str(x)[:4]}.'
        f'{str(x)[4:6 if len(str(x)) > 7 else 5]}.{str(x)[-2:]}')
    output[ws] = df
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('TestOutput.xlsx')

for ws, df in output.items():
    df.to_excel(writer, index=None, sheet_name=ws)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

But the output has a bug and in some data the numbers of months are rewritten next to the numbers of the day.

[image]

Like 2021.3.32, in fact, such a number did not exist in my original data at all

Comment: How to interpret something like `2021111`: `2021.1.11` or `2021.11.1`?

Comment: Should the value 2021111 be parsed as 2021.01.11 or 2021.11.01? I think the formatting is not unambiguous.

Comment: What's your question? If you're looking for help fixing the bug, what have you already tried, and what didn't work? Please read [ask].

Comment: Where did you get this Excel file from? With an ambiguous date format like this, you might be better off getting a new file with an unambiguous date format or Excel's built-in date/time datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve the ambiguity for dates like `2021111`. In a first time, you can use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%Y.%-m.%-d')
print(df)

# Output
       date      date2
0   2021227  2021.2.27
1   2021228  2021.2.28
2    202131   2021.3.1
3    202132   2021.3.2
4    202133   2021.3.3
5    202136   2021.3.6
6    202137   2021.3.7
7    202138   2021.3.8
8    202139   2021.3.9
9   2021310  2021.3.10
10  2021313  2021.3.13
11  2021314  2021.3.14
12  2021315  2021.3.15
13  2021111  2021.11.1  # <- default interpretation of 2021111
```

Comment: Very kind of you :)